# Apply character operation to one list in single line of code

Tags: r, lapply

I want to generate the list ["chr1", "chr2", ... "chr22"]. The solution I came up with is to abstract out the operation of turning an integer into a chromosome name and then lapplying it:

```
toChromName <- function(x) {
  paste("chr", toString(x), sep = '')
}
autosomes = lapply(1:22, toChromName)
```

But I am wondering if there is a way to do this in one line, similar to using lambdas in Python.

Comment: use `paste("chr", x, sep= '')`

Comment: `as.list(paste0("chr", 1:22))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString` is not doing what is intended. `paste` is vectorized, so we can directly do this on a `vector` of numbers instead of looping each element and applying the function

```
paste0("chr", 1:22)
```

ie.

```
toChromName <- function(vec) {
            paste0("chr", vec)
  }
toChromName(1:22)
#[1] "chr1"  "chr2"  "chr3"  "chr4"  "chr5"  "chr6"  "chr7"  "chr8"  "chr9"  "chr10" "chr11" "chr12" "chr13" "chr14" "chr15" "chr16" "chr17" "chr18"
#[19] "chr19" "chr20" "chr21" "chr22"
```

If it is needed in a `list`, use `as.list` to convert to a `list`

```
as.list(toChromName(1:22))
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'not doing what is intended'? When I view the results of the two versions, they look identical. Do you mean it's unnecessary?

Comment: @GretchenW  `toString` is doing `paste(., collapse=', ')`   Here, we don't need that and that is the reason I mentioned

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions, @akrun!

Comment: @GretchenW  Glad that the answer helps you.  Thank you